# Pandas search for duplicate rows in one column which have different values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` for which I want to find all rows for which the value of column `A` is the same, but the value of column `B` different, e.g.:

```
       | A | B
    ---|---|---
     0 | 2 | x 
     1 | 2 | y
```

I know I can use `pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby('A') if len(g) > 1)` to get the rows with duplicate values of `A`, but how do I add the second constraint?

Answer (score 6):

Thinking about this, it makes sense to call `unique` on the `groupby`:

```
In [213]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':2, 'B':list('xxyzz')})
df

Out[213]:
   A  B
0  2  x
1  2  x
2  2  y
3  2  z
4  2  z

In [229]:
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.unique()).reset_index()

Out[229]:
   A          B
0  2  [x, y, z]
```

Comment: I think you need to expand the result from Out[229] next, so that you have three rows for the two columns. Then the answer would be complete.

Comment: @Make42 I'm still waiting for the desired output, the OP never responded

Comment: I think the provided table is both the example and the desired output.

Comment: @Make42 you mean like the output from this: `df.groupby(['A','B']).filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)`?

Comment: No, I'd expect `pd.DataFrame({'A':2, 'B':list('xyz')})` as the final result. It is actually an important question how to do the last transform.

Comment: @Make42 then the output is no different than `df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Mmmh... true story. You are right. I thought it might be interesting if there are other columns as well, but `drop_dublicates()` allows to specify which columns to consider.

Answer (score 5):

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x['B'].unique()) > 1)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know this.

Answer (score 0):

This will print columns' name which have duplicate values group by one column you want.

```
a = []
for c in df.columns:
    for i in df.groupby(['A'])[c].unique().values:
        if len(i) > 1:
            a.append(c)
            break
        else:
            pass
print(a)
```